# Why is pg_query_params() doesn't return anything?

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm taking parameters from a user and trying to insert into 'users' table.
However, it appears `pg_query_params()` doesn't return anything from below code.

```
    $sql = <<<EOF
INSERT INTO users VALUES($1, $2, $3, DEFAULT, $4, $5, $6, $7::integer, $8, $9, $10, $11)
RETURNING "User Unique ID";                             
EOF;
echo("Pass 3");

$response = pg_query_params($db, $sql, array($ipaddress, $country, $time, $phone, $email, $hashed_pwd, $thirdpartyid, $logintype, $appId, $code, $verified));
echo("pg_query_params response ");
echo($response);
if ($arr = pg_fetch_assoc($response))
{
    $userId = $arr['User Unique ID'];
    echo("Yes");
}
else
{
    echo("No");
    $userId = NULL;
}
print_r($userId);
```

The 'users' table look as the following.
[image]

I'm echoing 'No' meaning that $response is not correct.
Can anyone point out what mistake I'm making here?

Comment: Have you tried to check for the error using `pg_last_error`?

Comment: Be aware of the difference between [Heredoc and Nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) strings re: variable interpolation. I'm assuming your `$1` etc. are a part of PostgreSQL prepared statement, and you're not intending to interpolate literal `$1, $2` etc. into your query.